# Update elements property binding

Tags: polymer, lit-element

I have an LitElement based web component, that renders a mdw-dialog with a custom element inside that uses a property from the parent component. When user click an a button, the dialog is shown that renders a couple of input fields. This all works great, but I want the property to be reset to an empty object whenever the button is clicked, before the dialog is shown and though I can easily do so - it does not appear to have an effect on the dialog elements.

Parent element

```
export class PageApplications extends LitElement {

    static get properties() {
        return {
            application: { type: Object }
        }
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.application = {};
    }

    onMouseOver(event) {
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('mwc-fab').extended = ('mouseenter' === event.type);
    }

    openDialog() {
        console.log('PageApplication.openDialog:', this.application);
        this.application = {};
        let dialog = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('mwc-dialog');
        dialog.requestUpdate;
        dialog.open = true;
    }

    closedDialog(event) {
        console.log('closedDialog:', this.application)
        if ('ok' === event.detail.action) {
            // NOP
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log('PageApplication.render', this.application);
        return html`
            <style type="text/css">
                mwc-fab {
                    position: fixed;
                    right: 1rem;
                }
                mwc-list {
                    background-color: #FFF;
                }
            </style>
            <mwc-fab showIconAtEnd icon="add_circle" label="New Application" 
                @mouseenter="${this.onMouseOver}"
                @mouseout="${this.onMouseOver}"
                @click="${this.openDialog}"
                >
            </mwc-fab>
            <mwc-dialog heading="Create Application"
                @closed="${this.closedDialog}">
                <cnvy-create-application
                    .application="${this.application}"
                ></cnvy-create-application>
                <mwc-button
                    slot="primaryAction"
                    dialogAction="ok"
                >Create</mwc-button>
                <mwc-button
                    slot="secondaryAction"
                    dialogAction="cancel"
                >Cancel</mwc-button>            
            </mwc-dialog>
            <h2>Applications</h2>
```

as you can see the application property is bound to element cnvy-create-application

```
export class ConvoyCreateApplication extends LitElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            application: { type: Object }
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log('ConvoyCreateApplication.render', this.application);
        return html`
            <style>
                mwc-formfield {
                    display: block;
                }
            </style>
            <mwc-formfield>
                <mwc-textfield 
                    placeholder="Name" 
                    helper="Name of application"
                    .value="${this.application.name}"
                    @change="${e => this.application.name = e.target.value}"
                    ></mwc-textfield>
            </mwc-formfield>
            <mwc-formfield>
                <mwc-textarea 
                    rows="2" 
                    placeholder="Description" 
                    helper="Short description"
                    .value="${this.application.description}"
                    @change="${e => this.application.description = e.target.value}"
                ></mwc-textfield>
            </mwc-formfield>
        `;
    }

}
customElements.define('cnvy-create-application', ConvoyCreateApplication);
```

Problem is - the first time I click the button, the dialog is shown as expected and each textfield says "undefined", which is probably ok as props are not defined in empty object. 
I enter value respectively "a" and "b" and click ok in the dialog and console prints

```
closedDialog: {name: "a", description: "b"}
```

as expected. If I then click button again, the "application" property should be reset to empty object but UI shows textfields with "a" and "b", and if I change "b" to "d", only "d" is sent back

```
closedDialog: {description: "d"}
```

meaning the application object was infact reset to empty, BUT this is not what is shown ... so, how do I trigger the update? I've tried various "update", "requestUpdate" .. and such lifecycle methods but to no avail ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mwc-textfield` internally uses a native `input` and passes the `value` property binding to it. This is one of the cases where a property is updated from multiple sources (from `.value="${this.application.name}"` and from the DOM when editing the text). In this scenario `lit-html` may not know how to update the value and can cause a misalignment between the data and what's actually shown. To solve this you can use the [`live` directive](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#live): it

> checks binding value against the *live* DOM value, instead of the previously
>   bound value, when determining whether to update the value.

```js
import {live} from 'lit-html/directives/live';

// ...

render() {
  return html`
    <mwc-textfield
      .value=${live(this.application.name)}
               ^^^^
    ></mwc-textfield>
  `;
}
```

---

In `openDialog()` you have probably missed the parenthesis in `dialog.requestUpdate˅;` although there's no need to call it: `this.application = {};` is sufficient to trigger an update.

To prevent the textfields from showing `undefined` you can either provide a fallback value in the binding

```html
<mwc-textfield
  .value=${live(this.application.name || '')}
></mwc-textfield>
```

or initialize the entire data structure with empty values:

```js
constructor() {
  this.application = {
    a: '',
    b: '',
    // ...
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Umbo - that did infact solve my problem, adding the live directive/function.. great stuff! :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)